# I write a code on above question but didn't fill the criteria as per requirement of question. Please give me suggestion so that i can complete it

Tags: oracle, plsql

Q- /*Write a function to create table which contain columns ID and BALANCE and insert record in the way  if  Column ID between 1 to 25 BALANCE will increase by 10
(ID    BALANCE

1              10

2                20

.

.

25        250)

If  column ID between 26 to 50 the BALANCE will be

( ID    BALANCE

```
          26  26+10
```

27   27+20

.

.

50      ).*/
/*I write that code and the function also compiled but data didn't insert into the table.
Please find my code below here.*/

```
create or replace function t1
return varchar2 as
pragma autonomous_transaction;
cursor c1 is
select columnid,balance from dept1;
emp_rec c1%rowtype;
counter number(2):=1;
bal number:=10;
begin
open c1;
loop
fetch c1 into emp_rec;
exit when c1%notfound;
insert into dept1(columnid,balance) values(counter,bal);
counter:= counter+1;
bal:=counter*10;
end loop;
close c1;
return 'true';
end;
/
```

Comment: Did you execute the function? Where is the `COMMIT`? Why did you specify autonomous_transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several weak points:

- Why do you use `pragma autonomous_transaction`? I don't see any reason for it
- Do you know table `dept1` has exactly 50 rows? Maybe there are more or less. I assume this table is empty, that's the reason why nothing is inserted, the loop is never executed.
- You entirely missed the second requirement for rows 26-50
- You process the rows one-by-one. In a real live application, this may cause performance issues. Of course, not for 50 rows but it's about principles.

Oracle provides a row-generator function, a simple solution could be this one:

```
create or replace function t1 return varchar2 as
begin

   insert into dept1(columnid,balance)
   SELECT 
       LEVEL AS counter, LEVEL * 10 AS BALANCE
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 25
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
      25 + LEVEL AS counter, (25 + LEVEL) + LEVEL * 10 AS BALANCE
   FROM dual
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 25;

end;
```

Or, if you prefer, run two insert statements:

```
insert into dept1(columnid,balance)
SELECT 
    LEVEL AS counter, LEVEL * 10 AS BALANCE
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 25;

insert into dept1(columnid,balance)
SELECT 
    25 + LEVEL AS counter, (25 + LEVEL) + LEVEL * 10 AS BALANCE
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 25;
```

or use `CASE` expression

```
insert into dept1(columnid,balance)
SELECT 
    LEVEL AS counter, 
    CASE 
        WHEN LEVEL <= 25 THEN 
            LEVEL * 10 
        ELSE
            LEVEL + (LEVEL-25) * 10
    END AS BALANCE
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 50;
```